# threading - how to get parent id/name?

Tags: python, multithreading

I looking for the way to get parent ID or name from child thread.
In example, I have main thread as MainThread. In this thread i create a few new threads. Then I use `threading.enumerate()` to get references to all running thread, pick one of child threads and somehow get ID or name of MainThread. Is any way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a Thread subclass that sets a `parent` attribute on init:

```
from threading import current_thread

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parent = current_thread()
        Thread.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Then, while doing work inside a thread started with this class, we can access `current_thread().parent` to get the spawning Thread object.

Comment: Oh I like. This idea has some self-checking possibilities. You might want to make mythread.parent a property that returns False if the parent "not is_alive()". Or make a MainThreadChild class with a class attribute "parent" instead of an instance attribute "parent" so that all threads of this type are basically expecting to be bound to a certain thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a reference to parent thread on child thread.. and then get it's ID

Answer (score 0):

You might want to pass the name of MainThread to the child threads on creation.

Another option, if you're working with a class, is to have the target of the child threads point to a method from the class of MainThread:

```
class MainThread:
    name = "MainThreadName"

    def child_thread_run(self):
        print self.name # Will print "MainThreadName", even from a child thread

    def run(self):
        child = threading.Thread(target=self.child_thread_run)
        child.start()
```

Comment: This is a very poor approach.