# Python: setting __globals__ for modules and their imports

Tags: python, testing, module

I'm developing a test engine with Python, but I'm facing some problems related to module loading and global functions.

The main idea of the framework I'm creating is to load a Python file containing functions and annotations "@thisisatest" to tell which functions are tests. I load this file with imp.load_source, and latter, I spawn threads that calls the function from the loaded module. It's something like this:

```
module = imp.load_source("test", "testdir/test.py")
function = module.testFunction
thread = threading.Thread(target=function)
thread.start()
```

Anyway, I want to connect to this test a "assertion function", doing something like:

```
module = imp.load_source("test", "testdir/test.py")
module.__globals__.assertAndTerminate = assertionFunction
function = module.testFunction
thread = threading.Thread(target=function)
thread.start()
```

And that's all right. The problem starts when the test.py imports another module that uses the assertAndTerminate function inside it. The module loaded by test.py is completely unaware from the __globals__ from test.py and don't know who's the assertAndTerminate I'm talking about (and that makes sense, since each module has its own __globals__).

Does anyone know a way I could set the same assertAndTerminate function for the test.py module and the modules loaded by it in a thread? I would prefer not searching for imports in a tree, is it possible?

Is there something like `Thread(target=function, global_vars=["assertAndTerminate":assertionFunction])`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the attribute *directly* on the module; that *is* the global namespace for that module:

```
module = imp.load_source("test", "testdir/test.py")
module.assertAndTerminate = assertionFunction
```

You do *have* to set globals on a per-module basis. Globals from one module do no not propagate to other modules on import.

You *can* add to the `__builtin__` module (`builtin` in Python 3):

```
import __builtin__

__builtin__.assertAndTerminate = assertionFunction
```

These are then visible in **all** modules:

```
>>> import __builtin__
>>> __builtin__.foobar = 'barbaz'
>>> foobar
'barbaz'
```

Generally speaking, you *really* want to avoid doing this. Find some other method to solve your problem. Import code instead of relying on globals being set.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Martijn. But I think I'have forgotten a important think, this function "assertAndTerminate" must be different from thread to thread. Is there a way I can set a builtin attribute for a thread or process?

Comment: @GustavoMeira: No, there is not. You'll have to set a function that checks a thread-locals mapping to dispatch to the right method.

Comment: @GustavoMeira: In other words, have `assertAndTerminate` be a wrapper method that does the per-thread dispatching.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just have one problem with this, some of the tests are importing libs that spawns other threads, and theses threads also can be using the assertAndTerminate function. I could spawn new processes too, but anyway, I could import a test.py that could spawn new processes too...

Comment: @GustavoMeira: Sounds like you need to rethink what you are trying to do then (which is not clear to me at all). Why do you need to have global functions in the first place? Why can't these functions be imported by the test code itself?

Comment: these assertion functions can be imported with no problems. I just wanted them to be simpler as possible to the developer. I just wanted to define one assertion function per thread visible in its global scope, but the imports doesn't let me.

Comment: The import can provide a wrapper function too, which dispatches according to the thread that calls it. Don't stuff things in the built-in namespace; explicit imports are better than an implicit magic function.

Comment: I agree with you about "implicit magic function", so it's important to have an import that defines the assertion function. But the problem happens when I spawn thread A as a test. Thread A spawns another thread called B (don't matter if A and B are defined in the same module). When B calls the assertion function, the assertion function should know the root thread (A, who's started the test) so it could notify the test summary.

Comment: You could experiment with the [`current_thread()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.current_thread) function, together with the `.parent` attribute of the returned `Thread` object. This requires your tests to use the [`threading` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html), but it'd be a start. That way you could detect if a child thread was spawned, and still return the 'per thread' object for that *set* of threads.

Comment: Thanks, Martijn, this is the way I'm going to take.

Comment: @GustavoMeira: Sorry, I misread something; there is *no* `.parent` attribute on `Thread` objects; you'd need to set that explicitly. Your API users would have to either provide that attribute explicitly, use only your subclass of `Thread` that sets that attribute implicitly (see [Python threading - how to get parent ID/name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6552097)) or retrieve an object per main thread then share that object between spawned threads.